# ERROR: Could not get unknown property 'FabricApiKey' for ProductFlavor_Decorated

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

> ERROR:

```
Could not get unknown property 'FabricApiKey' for
ProductFlavor_Decorated{name=play, dimension=store,
minSdkVersion=null, targetSdkVersion=null, renderscriptTargetApi=null,
renderscriptSupportModeEnabled=null,
renderscriptSupportModeBlasEnabled=null,
renderscriptNdkModeEnabled=null, versionCode=null, versionName=null,
applicationId=null, testApplicationId=null,
testInstrumentationRunner=null, testInstrumentationRunnerArguments={},
testHandleProfiling=null, testFunctionalTest=null, signingConfig=null,
resConfig=null, mBuildConfigFields={}, mResValues={},
mProguardFiles=[], mConsumerProguardFiles=[],
mManifestPlaceholders={}, mWearAppUnbundled=null} of type
com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.ProductFlavor.
```

My code is

```
flavorDimensions "store"
productFlavors {
    fdroid {
        dimension "store"
    }
    play {
        dimension "store"
        resValue 'string', 'io.fabric.ApiKey', FabricApiKey         //error here
        resValue "bool", "com.crashlytics.RequireBuildId", "false"
    }
}
```

I'm having trouble failing synchronization on the Android Studio app when opening a project that was created earlier. Because when synchronization fails, the xml listings and so on cannot be displayed. How to overcome these problems

Comment: Please include a description of your problem, what you're trying to accomplish, and what you've done to try to resolve the error. It'll make it easier for folks to help you. It's not enough to post just an error message and code block.